# While make frequent request on Chrome.Getting Aw snap! error

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery-file-upload

I'm uploading the big files using chunk method.If i make minimum number request to the server uploading is working fine.if make high number of request to the server Chrome browser has crashed with Aw Snap! error message.But other browsers are working fine with high number of request.

How to resolve this.Is there workaround?is it chromium bug?

**Updated**

Below function will slice the file then upload chunk to server .After all chunks uploaded. Merge Api will merge the chunk.

**Code:**

```
function readFile (file) {   

                var uploadBatchKey = this.guid;

                var start = 0; //Start Index
                var stop = file.size; //End Index
                var chunksize = (document.getElementById('chunkSize').value * 1048576);
                var index = this.chunkUploadIndex;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var filecontent = null;

                var waitingInterval = null;
                var totalsegment = Math.ceil(stop / chunksize);
                var isPreviousChunkUpload = true;
                var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(JSViewmodel.SelectedFiles(), function (item) {
                    return item.UploadManager == undefined ? false : (uploadBatchKey === item.UploadManager.guid);
                });
                match.UploadBatchKey(uploadBatchKey);

                var handle = setInterval(function () {

                    if (isPreviousChunkUpload) {

                        if (!match.IsUploading()) {                         
                            clearInterval(handle);
                        }
                        else if (index > totalsegment) {
                            isPreviousChunkUpload = false;
                            var filename = match.IsRelativePath() ? file.webkitRelativePath : file.name;
                            console.log(file.size);
                            var batchData = { uploadBatchKey: uploadBatchKey, fileName: filename, fileSize: file.size };
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/Home/MergeChunk",
                                type: 'POST',
                                async: false,
                                data: batchData,
                                success: function (result) {
                                    debugger;
                                    console.log(result);
                                    if (result == "False")
                                        match.IsFailed(true);                                    
                                },
                                error: function (result) {
                                    console.log(result);
                                    debugger;
                                    match.IsFailed(true);
                                }
                            });

                            match.IsUploading(false);
                            match.IsCompleted(true);
                            clearInterval(handle);
                        }

                        start = (index - 1) * chunksize;
                        stop = (index * chunksize) - 1;
                        reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                                filecontent = evt.target.result;
                                var chunkContent = { chunkContent: window.btoa(filecontent), chunkIndex: index - 1, uploadBatchKey: uploadBatchKey };
                                console.log("onloadend" + chunkContent.chunkIndex);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/Home/Upload",
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    async: false,
                                    data: chunkContent,
                                    success: function (result) {                                        
                                        match.Percentage(Math.round((chunkContent.chunkIndex / totalsegment) * 100));
                                        isPreviousChunkUpload = true;
                                    }
                                });                                
                            }
                        };                        
                        var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
                        isPreviousChunkUpload = false;
                        console.log("file slice:" + index);
                        index++;
                        match.UploadManager.chunkUploadIndex = index;
                    }


                }, 500);
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your code? There is no problem to limit number of requests but may be the problem is not into request number.

Comment: oh got it.Give me a minute will post